# Qt Creator Qt 5.7, OpenGL functions not found

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am using the Qt Creator IDE and the Qt 5.7 framework for my program. I have a widget in my form. This widget is controlled by OpenGL. To be more specific, I want to draw shapes with OpenGL on that widget. However, I can't use glGenVertexArrays or glBindVertexArray.
I get these errors:

```
'glGenVertexArrays': identifier not found
'glBindVertexArray': identifier not found
```

GLWidget.h:

```
#ifndef GLWIDGET_H
#define GLWIDGET_H

#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>

class GLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit GLWidget(QWidget *parent);

protected:
    void initializeGL() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    void paintGL() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    void resizeGL(int w, int h) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
};

#endif // GLWIDGET_H
```

GLWidget.cpp

```
#include "glwidget.h"

GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) : QOpenGLWidget(parent)
{

}

void GLWidget::initializeGL() {
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

void GLWidget::paintGL() {
    GLuint VertextArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertextArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertextArrayID);
}

void GLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h) {

}
```

.pro file

```
QT       += core gui opengl

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = QtOpenGLTest
TEMPLATE = app

LIBS += -lOpenGL32
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    glwidget.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    glwidget.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vertex arrays-related functions are not in `QOpenGLFunctions`, as that class aims at the common subset of OpenGL 2.1 (+FBO) and OpenGL ES 2.

They're available in other ways:

- QOpenGLExtraFunctions (aiming at GL 3.x + extensions / ES 3.x)
- QOpenGLVertexArrayObject (wrapper class for the functionality)
- QOpenGLExtension_ARB_vertex_array_object (which just wrapper the corresponding extension. This won't work on ES 2, where you got the `OES_` extension, or on Apple devices where you got the `APPLE_` extension).